# Spring WebFlux - a single method to handle 404?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

Doing my first steps in WebFlux, I've few RestController classes that expose GET API to retrieve a resource by id from the server, for example:

```
@GetMapping("{id}")
public Mono<Customer> findById( @PathVariable int id )
{
    return Mono.justOrEmpty( service.getById( id ) );
}
```

Assuming service.getById() returns NULL in case requested id is not found, how do I convert it into HTTP code 404 with some custom message?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to wrap the Customer in a ResponseEntity, 
I assume your service is returning a Mono .. if not wrap in a `Mono.fromCallable(() -> service.getById())`

```
e.g. 
    @GetMapping("/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<ResponseEnity<?>> findById( @PathVariable int id )
    {
        return service.getById(id)
                .map(customer -> ResponseEntity.ok(customer))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>("{\"content\":\"false\"}", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to use this approach to return a custom JSON with the 404 error code to the end user?

Comment: ResponseEntity.notFound().body("{\"custom_json......}).build() or throw an error and catch it in a ExceptionHandler

Comment: ResponseEntity.notFound() doesn't have body(), I'm using v2.0.3.RELEASE.. So ExceptionHandler is the only way?

Comment: @Seffy updated, you can create a new Response Entity, and don't forget the contenttype header